# Bulk delete address@ across multiple accounts

Tags: email, bash

On a webhosting server, each user (of hundreds) has an email account test@(their_domain)

I want to delete them all using a bash script but can't write something like that.

Essentially I want to traverse `/home/*/mail/*` and `rm -rf /home/*/mail/*/test` if it exists

Can anyone help me out?

Comment: So, did you try the `rm` command and it didn't work?

Comment: Sure.  I knew I could do that manually, but the important bit was "I want to delete them all using a script"  See my answer below.

Comment: My point is: `rm -rf /home/*/mail/*/test` **is** a script, just put it in a file, make it executable and add `#!/bin/bash` as the first line.

Comment: Thanks...I wasn't sure what was even possible and your comment wasn't quite enough to go on.  I learned something, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The script solution was to dissect some other scripts to learn more and I ended up using `find /home/*/mail/* -name "smtp" -exec rm -rf {} \;`

I learned a lot...if you wouldn't have known the answer yourself look up the difference between ending the script with a `+` or a `;`

However this didn't solve my problem, as Gerald Schneider notes in the comments, it only deletes the data file.  I need instead to use cpanel's /scripts/delpop

But `find /home/*/mail/* -type d -exec /scripts/delpop smtp@{} \;` results in smoething like `/scripts/delpop smtp@/home/example/mail/example.com` which obviously won't work.  Perhaps this should be another question, but I will post the answer here when I figure it out.

Comment: The last few words should read: a `+` or a `;`. Another typo: `/;` instead of `\;`.

Comment: You could simply do: `find /home/*/mail/* -name "smtp" -delete` (if `-delete` is implemented in your version of `find`), as this option will not have to spaw a process for each file,  or: `find /home/*/mail/* -name "smtp" -print0 | xargs -0 rm -f`

Comment: @PiotrP.Karwasz thanks, yes the forward slash was a typo, but doesn't the ; have to be escaped?

Comment: Yes, it does, otherwise `bash` takes it as the optional end of command and does not pass it to `find`.

Comment: sigh...misunderstanding...I now see what you meant...I had a } instead of ; and have fixed it.

Comment: Note: You are not deleting mail accounts this way. You are just deleting the data files. The mail accounts most probably still exist somewhere else, depending on the setup of your mail server software. When a new mail arrives to these addresses the data files will be recreated.

Comment: @GeraldSchneider yes I have discovered this.  I have also discovered cpanel has /scripts/delpop which will delete and email account.  Now I have to figure out how to extract just the directory name from the full path when doing a find by directory.